# Resolving a promise after some time t or if an event fires, whichever occurs first

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, eventemitter

I have a function called `wait` which accepts time in milliseconds and returns a promise. The promise should get resolved if `myEvent` is fired or after some time `ms` whichever occurs first. Currently I am doing something like this which I don't think is the right way to do it.

```
async function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((res) => {
        myEmitter.on('myEvent', res);
        setTimeout(res, ms);
    });
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't the caller like to know the difference between the event and the timeout?

Comment: @jfriend00 Not necessary for my use case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is fine.¹ Once the promise is settled (by the first call to the `resolve` function or `reject` function, to use their usual names), calling the `resolve`/`reject` functions again doesn't do anything at all. So what you have is the simple way to write it.

If you were doing something with a side effect like `res(doSomethingAndReturnValue())` in the event handler or timeout handler, *that* wouldn't be a good idea because the `doSomethingAndReturnValue()` part still executes and has its side effects. But in your example you aren't doing that.

---

¹ Three fairly minor notes:

1. I assume that when your event handler is called, some information is passed to the handler. Since you're using `res` directly as the handler, it will receive that information. So you have it set up to fulfill the promise with the value the event handler gets (if the event fires first), or with `undefined` (if the timer fires first), which means the code using it sees varying fulfillment values.
2. Typically I'd expect a timeout to be a rejection rather than a fulfillment, but it depends on your use case.
3. Your function doesn't need the `async` modifier, because it never uses `await`. A function doesn't need `async` just because it returns a promise. As of a normative change to the spec a year or so back, it no longer makes a difference if you return a native promise from an `async` function as you're doing (it used to delay things ***very*** briefly), but there's no reason for it.

Comment: I am emitting the event like so, without any data. `myEmitter.emit('myEvent')`
This makes the wait function return undefined always I think. About the async part, yeah I don't know why I put it there :joy

Comment: @AdityaDS - Heh, that's what I get for making assumptions. ;-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct. A promise can only be resolved once - if you resolve it twice, the second one is effectively a no-op.

With that said, as an alternative you can use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) which has the same idea. It takes promises as input and will produce a promise that settles when the first of the input of promises settles.

For example, clicking the button here settles a promise but it also gets settled in 10 seconds:

```js
let buttonResolve;
let buttonPromise = new Promise(res => buttonResolve = res);

document.querySelector("button")
  .addEventListener("click", buttonResolve)

let timedPromise = new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 10000));
let start = Date.now();
Promise.race([buttonPromise, timedPromise])
  .then(() => console.log(`finished in ${(Date.now() - start) / 1000}s`))
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Woah! Didn't know about `Promise.race` thanks for answering!

Comment: @AdityaDS - Yeah, `race` is one of the useful *promise combinators*. The full set is [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), [`race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race), [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), and [`any`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any). ...

Comment: ...[This post on the V8 blog](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators) gives a good overview of them.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot for sharing!